# I can load games, but starting a new game results in a black screen

Tags: technical-issues, red-dead-redemption-2

I bought a brand new pc and decided to revisit this piece of art.

I could load my previous saves normally, however I would like to start story mode from scratch.

The game loads up but just when the cutscene would start I get a black screen.

I tried some known fixes from related problems but none really did it:

- Whitelist game on firewall
- Disable vsync
- Delete "system.xml" from Settings folder

My GPU drivers are up-to-date. I'm running using an up-to-date DirectX 12, as Vulkan is broken for me (menus disappearing, textures not loading, that kind of stuff).

Current game build: 1491.18. I got the game directly through Rockstar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The installation of .NetFramework 3.5 (Redistributable) was corrupt.

As it has some dependencies, all I had to do was reinstall it.

[Here](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=21) is the official link.